# Splitting up a dataset in python

Tags: python

I have a dataset with about 500,000 records and they are grouped. I would like to shuffle and split into 10 smaller datasets based on the percentage weightings of each group. I want each dataset to contain all groups. Is there a library or method to do this in python?

1. I tried arry_split which just splits the dataset without stratification
2. Stratification on sckit learn does not really help since it uses training and test splits

Answer (score 0):

You can use k-fold splitting to achieve what you're looking for. Something like

```
folds = list(StratifiedKFold(n_splits=k, shuffle=True, random_state=1).split(X_train, y_train))
```

See the documentation here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html